# Passing command-line arguments to LaTeX document

Tags: command-line, latex, arguments

I have a LaTeX file, 'myfile.tex' say, that sometime in the middle of the code an ASCII file with LaTeX macros
has to be input, 'macrofile.tex, say, through an '\input{macrofile}' command. Actually, there are more than one 'macrofiles', so every time I have to edit 'myfile' and change the name of 'macrofile'. I can avoid the
edit part by using a \typein command, yet, I'd still have to enter the name from the keyboard. Is there any way to do that from the command line? So, to summarize, 'myfile.tex' looks like:

```
\documentclass{article}
........................
.......................
.......................
\begin{document}
.......................
......................
.......................
.......................
........................
.......................
\input{macrofile1} OR {macrofile2} OR {macrofile3} ETC...
.......................
......................
......................
....................
.....................
\end{document}
```

Can I pass the name of 'macrofile' as an argument to 'myfile.tex'?

Thanks

John

Comment: You have somehow managed to ask a question with exactly the same title as another question which asks the same thing: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1465665/passing-command-line-arguments-to-latex-document

Comment: That may be true, but *this* question helped me, and that one didn't.  I read that one first, too.

Answer (score 11):

Yup, something like:

```
latex "\def\myvar{info-to-pass} \input{<filename>}"
```

should do you. You can then use \myvar in your document.

The `\input{...}` specifies the filename for the `latex` command.